# How to add Pop up message from a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, popup

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="sub-total border text-center mt-2">
        <h6 class="font-size-12 font-raleway text-success py-3"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>order is eligible for FREE Delivery.</h6>
        <div class="border-top py-4">
            <h5 class="font-baloo font-size-20">Subtotal (<?php echo isset($subTotal) ? count($subTotal) : 0; ?> Item): &nbsp;<span class="text-danger">$<span class="text-danger" id="deal-price"><?php echo isset($subTotal) ? $Cart->getSum($subTotal):0; ?></span></span></h5>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mt-3">Proceed to Buy</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to add a popup message if I press the "Proceed to Buy" button?

Comment: What kind of popup message?

Comment: just simple text pop up that displaying text "Your order has been processed"...
i tried from youtube tutorial but idk why doesnt works...

Comment: Do you mean a JavaScript `alert()`?

Comment: yeah, how to add that?? can you help me?

Comment: Like this? https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

Comment: yess! thank you so much!! do i just need to copy paste it under the proceed to buy button?